# what should next step?? to run apt-get update , in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, updates

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
Fetched 204 kB in 7s (25.9 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
```

Comment: the next step is always `sudo apt upgrade` or `sudo apt full-upgrade` (use `apt` instead of `apt-get`for any Ubuntu 16.04 or newer).

Answer (score 1):

The next step is to see if there are updated or new packages. There are a few ways to do this.

1. The `apt-get` command will upgrade packages, but doesn't tell you about new packages. It is also all or nothing, unless you already know which packages have updates. If there is a lot of packages to update, it is preferable to do upgrade first then dist-upgrade/full-upgrade in order to reduce the load on the package resolver and reduce the possibility of erroneously removing packages.

   ```
   sudo apt-get upgrade #This updates packages that do not require updating others
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade #This updates all packages. apt-get full-upgrade is the same command
   sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade <packagename> #This will upgrade a specific package
   ```
2. `aptitude` is a text based package manager. It will give a list of packages broken into categories. Security Updates, Upgradeable Packages, and New Packages will be at the top. This gives you the option to selectively upgrade packages. It uses the resolver to handle dependencies, and shows what it is going to do before you commit. If you don't already have it, the following command will install it.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install aptitude
   ```
3. The GUI package manager. The package manager supplied with your desktop will usually filter by upgradeable packages and new packages.

No matter which method you use, it is recommend to apply all updates unless there is a specific reason not to; especially the security updates.